# Convert datetime to date in mm-dd-yyyy format to use with between clause in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

[image: table output]

I have the above table content and would like to get the below output.

[image: Final_output]

I wrote the below code :

```
SELECT  GROUP_NAME,CONVERT(date,creation_date,103),
SUM(case when Status='status 1' then 1 else 0 end) AS 'status 1',
SUM(case when Status='status 2' then 1 else 0 end) AS 'status 2',
SUM(case when Status='status 3' then 1 else 0 end) AS 'status 3',
SUM(case when Status='status 4' then 1 else 0 end) AS 'status 4',
SUM(case when Status='status 5' then 1 else 0 end) AS 'status 5',
COUNT(ticketnumber) AS GRAND_TOTAL 

FROM tablename WHERE CONVERT(date,creation_date,103) BETWEEN @from AND @to
GROUP BY GROUP_NAME,CONVERT(date,creation_date,103)
```

I am creating view which will be mapped to iservice tool. @from and @to will be an option to the user to select the dates.

Here i am unable to get the output as per the date selected by user.

For example, if the raw data has 4 tickets for Group A, but the output shows 3 ticket.

Need help to rectify the code or any simple way to write the above code.

I am using SQL 2012

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Could you please [edit] your question to make it a bit more understandable? See [ask] for information on how to properly ask a question. Tell us your [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Database_management_systems) as well since answers may be different for each DBMS. Help us help you!

Comment: I don't think you can do what you want with a view.  I think you need a user-defined function that returns a table, because you want to use parameters.

Comment: Thank you Gordon Linoff, I will not use the "between @from and @to" in the view. This is just to get help in rectifying the code.

Comment: Hi MBijen,I am using SQL 2012

Comment: Remove the field `convert(date),creation_date,103)` from SELECT and GROUP BY.

Answer (score 0):

You can just do like this with removing your group by on `Creation_date` - When you group by this you take all dates that differs from each other.

> NB: The where clause was only too show you how you could put it. I also corrected the code by removing the `)` after `convert(date)`

```
declare @table table (groupName nvarchar(50),create_date datetime,statusname nvarchar(50),ticket_number nvarchar(50))

insert into @table
Values

('Group A','2018-09-15','Status 1','A1'),
('Group B','2018-09-05','Status 3','A2'),
('Group C','2018-08-26','Status 5','A6'),
('Group C','2018-09-01','Status 4','A8'),
('Group B','2018-08-22','Status 2','A10'),
('Group C','2018-08-12','Status 3','A11'),
('Group A','2018-08-18','Status 5','A17'),
('Group B','2018-08-04','Status 5','A19'),
('Group C','2018-08-10','Status 4','A21'),
('Group A','2018-07-31','Status 2','A25'),
('Group B','2018-08-02','Status 1','A28'),
('Group C','2018-07-27','Status 3','A34'),
('Group A','2018-07-17','Status 2','A39'),
('Group B','2018-07-23','Status 4','A46'),
('Group C','2018-07-09','Status 2','A50'),
('Group C','2018-07-15','Status 3','A62'),
('Group B','2018-07-15','Status 5','A71'),
('Group C','2018-07-07','Status 5','A72'),
('Group A','2018-06-27','Status 4','B1'),
('Group A','2018-07-03','Status 2','B6')


SELECT
  GROUPNAME,
  sum(case when Statusname='status 1' then 1 else 0 end) as 'status 1',
  sum(case when Statusname='status 2' then 1 else 0 end) as 'status 2',
  sum(case when Statusname='status 3' then 1 else 0 end) as 'status 3',
  sum(case when Statusname='status 4' then 1 else 0 end) as 'status 4',
  sum(case when Statusname='status 5' then 1 else 0 end) as 'status 5',
  count(ticket_number) as GRAND_TOTAL 
FROM @table 
WHERE convert(date,create_date,103) between '2018-07-07' and '2018-08-01'
GROUP BY GROUPNAME
```

Comment: Hi Thomas, will consider your suggestion and implement this. Will share the update soon